# Android QR/Barcode Reader

Tags: android, zxing

I am using the [zxing IntentIntegrator](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) to scan either a barcode or a QR code from my Android app. Once the code is scanned, I need to identify whether the code was a QR code or a barcode. I am using the following code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent i) {
    IntentResult scan = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(request, result, i);
    if (scan != null) {
        format.setText(scan.getFormatName());
        contents.setText(scan.getContents());
    }
}
```

However `scan.getFormatName()` is being returned as `null`. Am I doing something wrong please?

Comment: Post your barcode? and are you sure you are invoking Barcode Scanner by Intent -- you are invoking with IntentIntegrator right?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code posted, I am invoking `IntentIntegrator`. I am using the [QR Code Generator from the ZXing Project](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator) to generate this [QR code](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=test) with text content

Comment: It just shows reading the result here, not invoking, but good because that rules out a few things. What happens if you use the ZxingTest app? Does it report format when you 'scan anything'?

Comment: No, it also results in `null` when I use the test app.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this with the latest Barcode Scanner and ZXingTest app on Google Play. When returning from scanning a QR code for example, `formatName` is "QR_CODE" and prints accordingly.

I still suspect that somehow you are trigger somebody's else app that is intercepting our `Intent`s. You're sure nothing else is on the device that is handling this and maybe not returning correctly?

Are you sure it's not that `scan` is `null` and just never setting the text?

Comment: The problem was with the `IntentIntegrator` jar file. I downloaded another jar file and it worked. If anyone finds the same problem, you should use [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing) demonstrating the use of `IntentIntegrator`

Answer (score 0):

see this code

```
 static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Button scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


      try {

Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
 {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No scanner found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

        }
    });

}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText("Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format);
        }
    }
}
```

in this you change intent.putExtra for QR code and barcode.